# HTACCESS recebe GET, mas impede recebimento de POST

Tags: php, html, htaccess

Estou usando o seguinte comando no HTACCESS para usar URL Amigáveis:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?id_cotacao=$1 [NC,L]
```

Está funcionando, o parâmetro está sendo recebendo pela URL da seguinte forma `site.com/proposta/310`, no caso o 310 é o ID do registro no banco.

Porém, tenho um formulário que possui sua ação neste mesmo arquivo. O formulário passa os valores via POST, mas o arquivo não identifica o método.

A intenção é que esse arquivo possa receber o formulário via POST e também o parâmetro via GET de forma "amigável".

Comment: Olá Rendesson, bem vindo. Tente adicionar na sua pergunta mais informações como a estrutura de pastas, onde está seu arquivo .htaccess o arquivo index.php, o erro da requisição POST e etc. Quanto mais informações você disponibilizar, mais fácil vai ser de alguém conseguir te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Sua regra aparentemente está construída de forma errada.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?id_cotacao=$1 [NC,L]
```

Você está dizendo que qualquer url que inicie com caracteres podendo conter azinho e zezinho, números coompreendidos entre zero e nove e caracter traço, sendo um ou mais caracteres serão reescritas se não houver diretórios no servidor com esse nome. Na realidade sua url inicia com a palavra "PROPOSTA" e o argumento passado é um inteiro.

o correto seria :

Use assim se o id da cotação utiliza  letras, números e traço:

```
RewriteRule ^proposta/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?id_cotacao=$1 [NC,L]
```

Ou assim, caso tenha apenas números como mencionado na pergunta.

```
RewriteRule ^proposta/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id_cotacao=$1 [NC,L]
```

Acredito que deva ser esse o problema, corrija e teste o seu GET e POST e sempre use o testador como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Url testador de htacess regex: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Resposta Atualizada:

Você consegue bloquear uma requisição post pelo htacess com essa condição

```
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
```

mas na pergunta apenas colou um trecho que nada tem a ver com o bloqueio de urls por POST ou GET. Nesse caso o bloqueio deve ser nos arquivos de configuração em seu servidor apache ou editou erradamente seu HTACCESS. Precisaria abrir o seu httpd.conf e verificar, não tenho maiores informações para te ajudar.

Pode usar sobre o comando no linux **whereis** **httpd.conf** para localizar o path para o diretório de instalação, arquivo de configuração do apache fica por lá.

Fique atento que sua regra não funciona se existir um arquivo (!-F) ou diretório (!-d) chamado proposta criado no servidor, devido a essas duas linhas de configuração.

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Essas são as orientações que posso te passar com que informou em sua pergunta se puder acrescentar mais informações talvez eu possa ir além.

Comment: Não resolveu o problema, inclusive, o GET também parou. "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: Editei minha resposta passando novas informações